# Fedora 26: Docker, NetworkManager, dnsmasq startup order

Tags: docker, fedora, dnsmasq, networkmanager

I am using Docker with Consul. I have configured NetworkManager to use dnsmasq and I configured dnsmasq to listen on the Docker interface `docker0`.

When the machine is booting, dnsmasq cannot find the `docker0` interface. When the system is booted up and I restart the NetworkManager, everything works as expected.

I suspect there is something wrong with the order in which the services are being started, but not sure exactly what the problem is.

Which step am I missing? Is this a bug? I found tutorials which describe this configuration as working for Fedora 25 but things may have changed in Fedora 26.